How to implement virtualization in a WinUI 3 ListView using IncrementalLoadingCollection?
I am working with WinUI 3 in C# and trying to enable virtualization in a ListView so that only the necessary items are displayed. I want to use the IncrementalLoadingCollection from the Windows Community Toolkit, but I encountered an issue where it cannot be found.
Installed the latest version of the Windows Community Toolkit NuGet package.(CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Helpers)
However, when I attempt to use IncrementalLoadingCollection, the compiler shows an error indicating it is not recognized.
    using Microsoft.UI.Xaml;
    using Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using CommunityToolkit.Common.Collections;
    using CommunityToolkit.WinUI;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Threading;
    using CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Helpers;
    
      public sealed partial class SampleControl : UserControl
      {
        public SampleControl()
        {
          this.InitializeComponent();
          
          // Error
          var collection = new IncrementalLoadingCollection<SampleDataIncrementalSource, SampleData>();
          MyListView.ItemsSource = collection;
    
        }
      }
    
      public class SampleData
      {
        public string data1 { get; set; }
        public string data2 { get; set; }
    
        public SampleData( string _data1, string _data2 )
        {
          this.data1 = _data1;
          this.data2 = _data2;
        }
      }
    
      public class SampleDataIncrementalSource : IIncrementalSource<SampleData>
      {
        private int _currentPage = 0;
        private const int _pageSize = 20;
    
        public async Task<IEnumerable<SampleData>> GetPagedItemsAsync( int pageIndex, int pageSize )
        {
          await Task.Delay( 0 );
    
          var items = new List<SampleData>();
          for( int i = 0; i < pageSize; i++ )
          {
            items.Add( new SampleData( 
                                       $"Data1-{pageIndex * pageSize + i + 1}",
                                       $"Data2-{pageIndex * pageSize + i + 1}" ) );
          }
          return items;
        }
    
        public async Task<IEnumerable<SampleData>> GetPagedItemsAsync( Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default )
        {
          var items = await GetPagedItemsAsync( _currentPage, _pageSize );
          _currentPage++;
          return items;
        }
      }


Make sure you installed the right NuGet package, CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Collections in this case. You can check it in the Windows Community Toolkit Gallery app.

Also, in the project file (*.csproj), edit the target versions to 22621.
<TargetFramework>net9.0-windows10.0.22621.0</TargetFramework>

You might also need this there:
<WindowsSdkPackageVersion>10.0.22621.38</WindowsSdkPackageVersion>

You can find more about this in the release notes.

Thank you for the advice! I’ve already applied those settings and have been using components like GridSplitter.
Could it be that IncrementalLoadingCollection is not part of Helpers?

It was present in CommunityToolkit.WinUI.Collections!

You were able to confirm it in the app? I didn't know that.
Thank you!
